# Define a class method in a module with a variable name

Tags: ruby, module, mixins, class-method

I created a module which is included in a class.  In the module, I am trying to define a method that is the downcased version of a class name without Filter. So ShowFilter would have a method called show that returns the class Show.  I get **"NoMethodError:
       undefined method `show' for ShowFilter:Class"**

```
module Filters

  module Base

    module ClassMethods

      @@filters = {}

      def filter name, &block
        @@filters[name] = block
      end

      def run query = {}
        query.each do |name, value|
          @@filters[name.to_sym].call(value) unless @@filters[name.to_sym].nil?
        end
        self
      end

      def self.extended(base)
        name = base.class.name.gsub(/filter/i, '')
        define_method(name.downcase.to_sym) { Kernel.const_get name }
      end


    end

    def self.included base
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

  end

end


class ShowFilter
    include Filters::Base

    filter :name do |name|
        self.show.where(:name => name)
    end

end
```

**EDIT: Example of use**

```
class ShowController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ShowFilter.run params[:query]
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, where's the `show` method?

Comment: define_method(self.name.downcase.gsub('filter', '').to_sym) { self }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `Filters::Base::ClassMethods`, it evaluates self in that context so the method you'll end up defining is `ClassMethods.classmethods` (since the gsub won't do anything).

Like the included hook you tapped into in Base, you want to use extended in ClassMethods:

```
module Filters
  module Base
    module ClassMethods

      @@filters = {}

      def filter name, &block
        @@filters[name] = block 
      end 

      def run query = {} 
        query.each do |name, value| 
          @@filters[name.to_sym].call(value) unless @@filters[name.to_sym].nil? 
        end 
        Object.const_get(self.to_s.gsub('Filter', '')) 
      end 

      def self.extended(base) 
        define_method(base.to_s.downcase.gsub('filter', '').to_sym) do 
          Object.const_get(self.to_s.gsub('Filter', '')) 
        end 
      end 
    end 

    def self.included base 
      base.extend ClassMethods 
    end 
  end 
end
class ShowFilter 
  include Filters::Base 

  filter :title do |title| 
    self.show.where(:title => title) 
  end 
end
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, new code is in original question.  I am still getting the error.  I am trying to define a filter DSL for mongoid models.  I want to be able to include the base filter module in several filter classes and access the model for that filter by its name "show" rather than something generic like "model"

Comment: Okay I updated my code. I'm still not sure what it should return. Is it `self.filter`? Or it would probably be a model called `self.downcase.gsub('filter', '')`

Comment: sorry i probably edited my code while you were working, take a look again at what its returning and it should be more clear.  Thanks for looking at this!  Basically ShowFilter should have a class method show that returns the class Show (not an instance but the class itself).  And a class BugsFilter would have a method bugs that returns the class Bugs.

Comment: Alright! There you go. So given WalrusFilter, you can do `WalrusFilter.walrus` and that will return the class `Walrus`.

Comment: Also make sure to remove the Show class definition (I'll remove from here). Otherwise I was getting errors about that.

Comment: Its working for you? I'm still getting the error when i run rspec

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14375/discussion-between-chris-and-chris)